# How to get rad text box value length throw javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using `radcontrols` in my project. How do I get rad text box value's length. If I entered `12345`, the length should be `5`.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
var textbox = document.getElementById("mytext");
var textlength = textbox.value.length;
```